# scaling the R exported plot to match R's output plot

Tags: r, plot, export-to-pdf

This may sound weird, or impossible but I can say the scale of the output plot when you compile inside R and view it without zooming or exporting works great for me. However, when I export to pdf, the plot becomes outrageously large and I never manage to scale it to what I see inside R. Am I being silly, or there is actually a difference and there is a way to get what I see inside that bottom-left-corner box of the R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ggsaves width and length arguments to get the desired size.

```
ggsave('name.pdf', width =14, height = 8)
```